# Is it possible to connect a USB-C external hard drive via a TB 2 -> TB 3 connector?

Tags: macos, mac, usb, external-hard-drive, macos-sierra

Using [this adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01NCO5PAH):

Is it possible to connect to to an iMac with the thunderbolt 2 port -> into the adapter -> into an external hard drive with the USB C connector?

Such as an [external USB-C HD like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AVF6UQQ)?

Wasn't sure if that will work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that hard drive is just USB 3.1, not Thunderbolt 3. A Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 1/2 adapter like the one you linked to wouldn’t do any good.

A simple USB 3.0 Type A male to USB Type-C Male cable (which that drive appears to include in-box!) should work.

Comment: Maybe this is a [better example](https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-10Gbps-Upright-cables-supports/dp/B01E80N2E8/ref=sr_1_5?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1494905131&sr=1-5&keywords=thunderbolt+enclosure). I am trying to get faster disk transfer speeds without breaking the bank on a full blown Thunderbolt enclosure, so I'd like to use the TB 2 bandwidth with a USB-C drive, which includes the latest SSD's, and possibly using a custom external NvME drive.

Comment: Same answer with that other product. Your iMac doesn't do USB 3.1, and these HD enclosures/docks you've been linking to don't do Thunderbolt 3. You're going to end up doing 5 Gbps USB 3.0 SuperSpeed at best. Don't be mislead by the USB-C port. If it doesn't say it does Thunderbolt 3 signaling over that port, it doesn't do it.